# Android how to add semcircle gradient shadow to a button?

Tags: android

only below the center of image and at the center.

Now, I only complete this by setting an image under this button, but not good.

[image: semicircle gradient shadow]

Comment: Can you elaborate the problem ?

Comment: Sorry , maybe not very clear about this question, my fault, the problem is how to canvas or use drawable xml to paint the  semicircle gradient shadow under a button?Am I  explaining it clear?